# Infopath get max() value from SharePoint column

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

How can I get the max value (the row with the greatest value for a particular column) from a SharePoint document library using Infopath and the Document Information Panel.

Tried max(.) it does not work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I tried this as well in Infopath but was unable to do so. In the end I was forced to write VSTA code for the infopath form, query the form, then executed a CAML query to get the max entry:

```
<View>
    <Query>
        <OrderBy>
            <FieldRef Name="yourColumn" Ascending="FALSE" />
        </OrderBy>
    </Query>
    <RowLimit>1</RowLimit>
</View>
```

Comment: is VSTA superseded by VSTO? I'm already using VSTO and I have a codebehind for my word document so I'm confused about if I should actually add VSTA or not. Thanks.

Comment: I haven't used VSTO, so I'm unsure how to go around your question. Are you using Infopath 2010?